# servant cannot stream JSON

Tags: haskell, streaming, servant

I try to stream JSON objects to clients in order to have update notifications.

My API is declared as following:

```
type API = "poll" :> StreamGet NewlineFraming JSON (SerialT IO Notification)
```

And I have got the following error:

```
• Could not deduce (ToJSON chunk0) arising from a use of ‘serve’
      from the context: P.Persist p
        bound by the type signature for:
                   app :: forall (p :: * -> *).
                          P.Persist p =>
                          PollRoute p -> P.Configuration p -> Application
        at app/Main.hs:93:1-70
      The type variable ‘chunk0’ is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance ToJSON DotNetTime
          -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.4.7.1:Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON’
        instance ToJSON Value
          -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.4.7.1:Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON’
        instance (ToJSON a, ToJSON b) => ToJSON (Either a b)
          -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.4.7.1:Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON’
        ...plus 46 others
        ...plus 70 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
```

I am using Servant 0.19.2. (`SerialT` comes from streamly)

Comment: Your type signature says you want the client to receive a value of type `SerialT IO Notification`.  I doubt you actually want to send an IO function to the client over HTTP, reconsider that type.

Comment: I actually have tested this case when I have done the Servant streamly support: [example](https://github.com/blackheaven/servant-streamly/blob/master/example/Main.hs#L38).

Comment: Do you have a minimal example that gives the type error?  The API seems fine (and I had no problem writing a streaming server for it), so the error must be elsewhere in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have used a custom streaming support library it should (the instance definition module) be imported during the server definition.